# NGRX - How to use filter to delete an item from an array?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to delete an item from an array but when I execute the code, it removes all the items from the state instead of the ones that dont have the specified ID.

```
    case REMOVE_STORE:
      return {
        Stores:[...state.Stores.filter( (item) => {
          item.storeId != action.payload
        })],
      };
```

I am able to remove an item by making use of slice, and the position of the element in the array but I would like to make use of the ID instead of the position in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `return` statement. Change you code to:

```
case REMOVE_STORE:
return {
    Stores: [...state.Stores.filter((item) => {
        return item.storeId != action.payload
    })],
};
```